# running a task on different hosts with intervals in ansible

Tags: ansible

this is my `task/main.yml`:

```
- name: Create and start services
  docker_compose: ...
```

and I have 3 hosts. I'd like this task will be run on each host with 3 minute intervals. 
for example: running on host1 at minute 0, running on host2 at minute 3 and running on host3 at minute 6. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's "pause" available in ansible playbook. Have you  tried it?
Here is the official doc : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html

As per this doc,

> To pause/wait/sleep per host, use the wait_for module.

you can use "wait_for" module : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#wait-for-module

Code snippet which you can use for "pause" :

```
tasks:
- name: Test
  pause: 
    minutes: 2
- name: Echo
  debug:
   msg: Test Pause
```

Code snippet for "wait_for"

```
tasks:
- name: sleep for 120 seconds and continue with play
  wait_for:
    timeout: 120
- name: Echo
  debug:
   msg: Test Pause
```